# Can the Scottish Parliament pass a law to stop labeling anything in imperial?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, scotland

As expected, The PM has responded with 'No' to a second Scotland referendum.
I was wondering what Scotland can do to 'protest' that and as per a discussion on my previous question ([What can Scotland legally do to get independence?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/48771/what-can-scotland-legally-do-to-get-independence)), I wonder if they can force this.

Examples:

- Speed limit signs to be in km/h
- Beer in pubs to be in ml, etc

By this law I mean force a 'Stop' using the imperial units all together rather than having them as an option beside the metric system.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No.  Weights and measures is a matter reserved for the UK government.**

The [Scotland Act, 1998](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/46/schedule/5/part/II), sets out that "Units and standards of weight and measurement" are a reserved matter (Schedule 5, Party II, Section C9), under the wider category of Trade and Industry.

They would need permission from the UK Government to ban imperial measurements, in the same way that they need permission to hold an independence referendum.